# Putting div elements inline

Tags: html, css

I want to make a timeline but it has broken structure. I think that is because of `display:inline`, and if I tried to do that to my site, it would break it.
`display: inline-block` also funks it up.

I tried to `display: inline` to the `overall` div containing the timeline and that didn't work. So then I did it to all the divs that were also in the timeline and that didn't work either.

Timeline:

```
<span class = "timelinefull">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="timeline">              
            <!-- ANCHOR DOT -->
            <div class= "dot">
                <div ng-mouseover="infoIsVisible = true" ng-mouseleave="infoIsVisible = false"   ng-mouseover="getCoords(event)">
                    <img class="icon" ng-src="img/icon_dot.png" height="30px" width="30px">
                </div> 
                <div class="info label label-info" id="info" ng-show="infoIsVisible">
                    <p>Was born</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- REST OF MY DOTS -->

            <div class="dot" ng-repeat="timelineEvent in timelineEvents">
                <timeline-info info="timelineEvent"></timeline-info>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Template for ng-repeat:

```
<div class="timeline-inner" ng-init="infoIsVisible= false">
    <img class="line" src="components/timeline/template-timeline/img/line.png" height="5px" width="{{ info.months }}">
    <div ng-mouseover="infoIsVisible = true" ng-mouseleave="infoIsVisible = false"   ng-mouseover="getCoords(event)">
        <a href="{{ info.link }}">
            <img class="icon" id="icon" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}" height="30px" width="30px">
        </a>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="info label label-info" id="info" ng-show="infoIsVisible">
    <p>{{ info.description }}</p>
    <p style="font-size: 8px"> Click for more info </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.timelinefull {
    display: inline;
}

.timeline-inner {
    display: inline;
}

.info {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.3s;
    transition:all linear 0.3s;
}

.line {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

.info.ng-hide {
    opacity:0;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `inline-block`? It's a magical combination

Comment: Please provide the related markup and css, completely

Comment: @Trix  https://jsfiddle.net/x9odh9ee/  not sure how to get the angular to work right on fiddle. Also in the orange box do you know why the shadow span at the bottom isn't completely spanning across the bottom?

Comment: Please be carefull and instead of putting so many script links, just share the complete HTML of the horizontal `dots` and stuff, instead of just saying `<!-- REST OF MY DOTS -->`. Also provide the related CSS

Comment: @Trix all of the css is there and the <!-- REST OF MY DOT--> was a personal note, all the other dots are made through ng repeat. I just needed an anchor dot because the ng repeat was line then dot after it.

Comment: Would u PLEASE provide ur complete code, instead of telling stories? Thanks

Comment: I swear that fiddle is everything! I don't really know how to work it to where it imports my angular! Im sorry! @Trix

Comment: problem is not angular, it is just incomplete markup. lets continue on the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101552/discussion-between-trix-and-user5812721).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options, to choose for the `display` property of an element in CSS:

**Inline elements:**

1. respect left & right margins and padding, but **not** top & bottom
2. **cannot** have a width and height set
3. allow other elements to sit to their left and right.

**Block elements:**

1. respect all of those
2. force a line break after the block element

**Inline-block elements:**

1. allow other elements to sit to their left and right
2. respect top & bottom margins and padding
3. respect height and width

So, it's better to put `display:inline-block` for elements with these classes:

- dot
- timeline-inner

like this:

```
timeline dot, timeline timeline-inner{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Please dont forget to put enough time to provide a summarized, though useful version of your code, including **Markup** and **CSS**, to let people reproduce final results.

Comment: Inline elements respect vertical padding, border and margin. However, only the `line-height` is used when calculating the height of the line box.

Comment: @Oriol tanx for the point, but I am pretty sure that `vertical margins`, `top` and `bottom`, are not accepted by inline-level elements.

Comment: Inline elements are tricky. Technically they accept vertical margins, see [Calculating heights - Inline](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced). But it's true that visually they aren't usually noticeable because they don't affect the height of the line box and are outside the border edge. They would be noticeable on an implementation which draws outlines outside the margin edge instead of the border one.

Comment: I had the same problem trying this as I did trying mani's suggestion: http://imgur.com/xWttfv5

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your CSS

```
.timeline, .timeline .dot, .timeline-inner, .timelinefull {
    display:inline-block;
}
.timeline, .timelinefull {
    width:100%;
}
```

**Update:**

Shot in the dark, without a snippet..

Could you add to your css

```
.dot .timeline-inner {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The above code will vertically center `.timeline-inner`. From your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9mei.jpg) it seems because the elements are now `display-inline` they only take up as much space as they need (the correct behaviour), however, you need the elements to align vertically centered within the `timeline`.

Comment: @user5812721 could you post a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with the generated html and combined css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x9odh9ee/  not sure how to get the angular to work right on fiddle. Also in the orange box do you know why the shadow span at the bottom isn't completely spanning across the bottom?